# Android Menu alignment

Tags: android

Hi
 in my application i have menu that contain 4 option , i need  to align the menu in the following format, 2X2

Comment: As I know we can't change the layout of menu. Although if you are using an OptionMenu, which contains four (or more) items, Android system will automatically make 2X2.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, but the menu aligns itself.  You have no control over it except adding options in order.